# Insert Data with AJAX PHP MySQL and wpdb->insert

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to achieve a simple custom AJAX request from my Wordpress Page.

I don't want to use form data but custom data from input fields.

When I try to use the data, that is send by the AJAX Call it does not work. Though it works when I do not send custom data within the AJAX Call and only trigger the insert.php file, where I manually set the Strings.

Can please anyone help me :) ?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="form-field-ajax_send_name">
<input type="text" id="form-field-ajax_send_detail">
<div id="ajax-send-button">SEND AJAX DATA</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.querySelector('#ajax-send-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            // AJAX aufrufen
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var method = 'POST';
            var url = 'insert.php';
            var data = {name: document.querySelector('#form-field-ajax_send_name').value, details: document.querySelector('#form-field-ajax_send_detail').value}
            var asynchronous = true;
            ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
            // AJAX Anfrage senden
            ajax.send(data);
            // Antwort der Anfrage erhalten
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    alert('Done!');
                } else if (this.status === 201) {
                    alert('Fehler!')
                }
            }
            ajax.onerror = function () {
                alert("Request failed");
            };
        })
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include_once "wp-config.php";
global $wpdb;
$p_name = $_POST["name"];
$p_details = $_POST["details"];
$insertedData = array(
    'name' => $p_name,
    'details' => $p_details,
);
$wpdb->insert('mytable', $insertedData);
?>
```

Comment: In PHP are `$_POST` values populated?

Comment: What do you mean by this :) ? Do I have to format the data another way?

Comment: Well it is unclear where the issue is currently because problem definition is "does not work". So does AJAX send data correctly, does PHP receive correctly, does wordpress process correctly? Those are three possible issues. Debugging POST array should remove JS/ajax issue, or identify it.

Comment: Good advise, thank you. So I echo(ed) the php variables in the AJAX response and they are empty :/ Any idea ?

Comment: Okay, so does running `console.log(document.querySelector('#form-field-ajax_send_name').value` in browser give you the result? This is a JS issue so my help there is limited. The PHP, MYSQL, and Wordpress tags can likely be removed as this is higher in the stack.

Comment: It does. it seems that the problem here is, that the data is not provided or fetched within the php script correctly.

Comment: `var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();` - why? Using jQuery is pretty standard within the WP environment, so what reason do you have not to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone :)

I found a solution. I needed to fix it within the js-code and set the request header first + then adapt the data so a string.

So **Javascript** AJAX would be:

```js
document.querySelector('#ajax-send-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    // AJAX aufrufen
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = 'POST';
    var url = 'insert.php';
    var data = 'name=' + document.getElementById('form-field-ajax_send_name').value + '&bestellung=' + document.getElementById('form-field-ajax_send_details').value;
    var asynchronous = true;
    
    ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    
    // AJAX Anfrage senden
    ajax.send(data);
    // Antwort der Anfrage erhalten
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            alert('Done!');
        } else if (this.status === 201) {
            alert('Fehler!')
        }
    }
    ajax.onerror = function () {
        alert("Request failed");
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> at first you confirm that your WordPress have connected with ajax CDN. If not connected then enque ajax CDN to your functions.php file.
> Then, Write HTML form like,

```html
<form>
   <label for="Name">Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
   <label for="Date of Birth">Date of Birth</label>
   <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob">
   <label for="Address">Address</label>
   <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="dataForm-submit">
</form>
```

> After Completed HTML Form, you write this Jscript Code,

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on('submit','#dataForm-submit', function(){
 jQuery.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
  data:'action=dataform_submition&'+jQuery('form').serialize(),
  success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

> Now, wirte your PHP functions page,

```
add_action('wp_ajax_dataform_submition', 'dataform_submition');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dataform_submition', 'dataform_submition');

function dataform_submition(){
 global $wpdb;
 $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'Your-Table Name';
 extract($_POST);
 $wpdb->query($wpdb->insert($table, array(name=>$name, dob=$dob, 
 address=$address), array('%s','%s','%s'));
 echo 'success';
 exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise, but I do not want to use data from a form + I would need to use JS and not jQuery :)

Comment: Okay. That mean you want to use node js. An I write?